# React router implement navlink using Material UI

Tags: reactjs, react-router, material-ui

I am new to react and I use UI Material for the design of my application that is divided into 3 parts on Nav, Header and Content. In the nav I put the links the problem is that I want to click on the link the information is seen in the Content and not in the Nav
How can I make the information appear in the Content and not in the Nav?

[Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZUyaN.png)

[New user](https://i.stack.imgur.com/21AL7.png)

Nav:

```js
      export default function NestedList() {
      const classes = useStyles();
      const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(true);

      const handleClick = () => {
        setOpen(!open);
      };
      return (
        <List
          component="nav"
          aria-labelledby="nested-list-subheader"
          subheader={
            <ListSubheader component="div" id="nested-list-subheader">
              Nested List Items
            </ListSubheader>
          }
          className={classes.root}
        >
          <ListItem button component={NavLink} to='/User/New'>
            <ListItemIcon>
              <accessibility/>
            </ListItemIcon>
            <ListItemText primary="New User" />
          </ListItem>
          <ListItem button>
            <ListItemIcon>
              <DraftsIcon />
            </ListItemIcon>
            <ListItemText primary="Drafts" />
          </ListItem>

            </List>
            );
          }
```

App:

```js
    return (
        <MuiThemeProvider theme={createMuiTheme()}>
          <Root config={presets.createCozyLayout()}>
            <CssBaseline/>
            <Header>
              <Typography>Header</Typography>
            </Header>
            <Router>
            <Nav>
                <NestedList/>  
                <Switch>
                  <Route exact path="/User/new" component ={NewUser}/>  
                </Switch>   
            </Nav>
            </Router>  
            <Content> 
                      Content
            </Content> 
          </Root>
        </MuiThemeProvider>
      );
    }
```

Comment: Router should be in Content and not at Nav.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The content which you want to display when your route changes must be in `<Content></Content>` tag.
So your code should be

```
<Content>
  <Switch>
  </Switch>
</Content>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `<Switch></Switch>` is in the wrong place. It should be in `<Content></Content>` and not in `<Nav></Nav>`